# Linq to return a new object with a selection from the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following object structure:

```
public class A
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IList<B> Values { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public List<A> IDs;
```

I would like to use Linq to query B and return a single instance of A with the single element of B in values. Is that possible? I currently do this with a foreach but I am thinking Linq would be neater.

```
foreach (A a in IDs)
{
    foreach (B b in a.Values)
    {
        if (b.Code == code)
        {
            return (new A()
            {
                ID = a.ID,
                Values = new List<B>()
                {
                    new B()
                    {
                        Code = b.Code,
                        DisplayName = b.DisplayName
                     }
                 }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `codeValue` in `if (codeValue.Value == value)`
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LINQ with the query-syntax:

```
return (from a in IDs
        from b in a.Values
        where b.Code == code
        select (new A
        {
            ID = a.ID, Values = new List<B>
            {
                new B
                {
                    Code = b.Code, 
                    DisplayName = b.DisplayName
                }
            }
        })).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
IDs.Where(a=>a.ID = id)
   .Select(a => new A() 
   {
       ID = a.ID,
       Values = new List<B>()
       {
           new B() 
           { 
               Code = a.Values.First().Code, 
               DisplayName = a.Values.First().DisplayName 
           }
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following in LinqPad (LinqPad.com)

```
void Main()
{
    List<A> IDs= new List<A>() {
        new A() { ID = "1", Values = new List<B>() {
                             new B { Code = "1", DisplayName = "1"}, 
                             new B { Code = "2", DisplayName = "2"},
                             new B { Code = "3", DisplayName = "3"} } },
        new A() { ID = "4", Values = new List<B>() { 
                             new B { Code = "4", DisplayName = "4"}, 
                             new B { Code = "5", DisplayName = "5"},
                             new B { Code = "6", DisplayName = "6"} } },
        new A() { ID = "7", Values = new List<B>() { 
                             new B { Code = "7", DisplayName = "7"}, 
                             new B { Code = "8", DisplayName = "8"},
                             new B { Code = "9", DisplayName = "9"} } }
    };

    A result = IDs.Where(a => a.Values.Any(b=> b.Code == "4")).FirstOrDefault();
    result.Dump();
    result = IDs.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Values.Any(b=> b.Code == "8"));
    result.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public IList<B> Values { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

You get this:

[image: result]

---

Prior edits follow:

With the edit to the question:

```
A result = IDs.Where(a => a.Values.Any(b=> b.Code == code)).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Original answer below

The following will return the first A element where ID = id

```
A result = IDs.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This makes it a list

```
List<A> result = IDs.Where(a => a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

Comment: *This makes it a list* Well `FirstOrDefault` looks like it would return a `bool`, so calling `ToList` on that probably won't work very well. At all. I think you meant `Where(a => a.ID == id)` but `FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id)` is probably better.

Comment: @ta.speot.is -- FirstOrDefault does not return a bool nor can it take a lamda as a parameter.  Please see the documentation. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx – Good point about where.

Comment: @Hogan `FirstOrDefault` can take a lambda as a parameter. Please see the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx :-)

Comment: Your original code was `IDs.Select(a => a.ID == id)`. This will take each item in `IDs` and evaluate it with `a.ID == id` which will return a `bool` for each item. You now have an `IEnumerable<bool>`. Calling `FirstOrDefault` on that will return ... a `bool`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - see code above, seems to work fine in LinqPad.